# A local Cohen-Macaulay ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

It may be a simple question, but I am stuck at:

> If $k$ is a field why $k[x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3]$ is Cohen-Macaulay when localized at the maximal ideal $(x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3)$?

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring is $2$-dimensional and $x^3,y^3$ is a regular sequence of length $2$.